# How to make vertical input fit entirely into the whole side navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I want the html text input field to complete overlap/imbricate its parent div.

I tried position absolute, top:0, bottom:0, left:0, right:0 on the input element to stretch it to the four corners of its parent div. I tried height:100%,width:100%, but the rotation makes it useless.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
div{
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  background:#111;
}
.field{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
   background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class='field' type='text' placeholder='Enter zipcode'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made an attempt to meet your scenario. It does not work in code snippet, however.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="textbox-element" class='field' type='text' placeholder='Enter zipcode'>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

div{
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
    background:#111;
}

.field{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color:blue;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var dimensions = document.querySelector("#container").getBoundingClientRect();
    var element = document.querySelector("#textbox-element");
    element.style.bottom = -dimensions.width;
    element.style.width = dimensions.height;
    element.style.height = dimensions.width;
});
```

What I'm doing here is to set the input's position and size after the DOM is loaded, meaning after the rotation is applied.

Comment: Basically I just want a retractable sidebar input field kinda thing. I am gonna put a button to retract this side input field.

Comment: Like this: https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/MvZyXr. On the side with 'x'

Comment: Yours doesn't work on CodePen. https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/XawRWv?editors=1010

Comment: It worked on my local HTML, I guess it's the positioning that needs adjustment based on your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is quite hard (if not impossible) with *just* CSS as the width & height cannot be determined.

The rotation is purely visual and does not affect the layout of elements around it.

You'd need JS, I'd suggest, to set the height and width of the rotated element to fit the parent div.

Something like this (using JQuery)

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {

  var width = $("div").height();
  var height = $("div").width();

  $(".field").css({
    width: width,
    height: height
  });
}).resize();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: green;
}

.field {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg);
  display: block;
  background: pink;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class='field' type='text' placeholder='Enter zipcode' />
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YxbNYd)

Comment: I want to essentially make a retractable input field. This is my retractble nav bar: https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/MvZyXr. I want to put the input field on the side with 'x'

Comment: What are you doing with `(window).on("resize", function(){.....}).resize();` What does `.resize()` at the end do? I get you need to resize the input every time the window changes.

Comment: It calls the resize function immediately on page load...it means I only need one function and not two.

Comment: here is my JS Code I don't know what is wrong: https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/PKvbeB?editors=0110